# Google charts: line break title in ColumnChart

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to split my title in my ColumnChart into 2 (or more) lines.

(see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

I tried using the pipe ("|") symbol as follows, but it doesn't work, neither does "\n".

```
var options = {"title":"My first line | \n this should be the second line!"};
```

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 3):

And in javascript, in your chart options variable, just add \n where you want a break, like:

```
vAxis: { title: "Line one of the title\nLine two of the title" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Visualization API charts don't support line breaks in the titles.  I am given to understand that support for using HTML is in the pipeline (which would allow you to use `<br />` tags for line breaks), so keep an eye out for announcements to that effect in the [Visualization API group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-visualization-api).

Answer (score 1):

The \n option seems to work now. I have just used:

```
var options = {title: 'Heading\nSub-heading'}
```

and got this output:

Heading
Sub-heading

Perhaps this is a recent addition.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone need this tips for add break line on ColumnName (DataTableChart) you can use `<br>` but need to add on chart `options : { allowHtml: true }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ASCII code 10.

In Ruby I used the following:

```
Label = first_line_string + 10.chr + second_line_string
```